# How to add dynamic table with function

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

How can I add to the table the row with some event and function

I have a problem with this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
var add=null;

function throw() {
var artist = document.getElementById("artist").value;
var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
var label = document.getElementById("label").value;

newRow = document.createElement("tr onclick='showRow(this)");
newRow.innerHTML = "<td>" + artist + "</td>" + "<td>" + title + "</td>" + "<td>"
        + label + "</td>";
add = document.getElementById("tabelkaa");
add.appendChild(newRow);
}
function showRow(x) {
alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
}
window.onload = function () {
var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
plus.addEventListener("click", throw);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
        <div id="info">
            <p>Artist <input type ="text" id="artist"> </p>
            <p> Title <input type ="text" id="title"> </p>
            <p>Label <input type ="text" id="label"> </p>

            <input type="submit" value="-" id="minus">
            <input type="submit" value="+" id="plus"> <br/>
        </div>
        <div id ="tabelka">
            <table id="tabelkaa" border="5">
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying to add 'onclick' in every row because I want to chceck and display the exact result.

Sorry if are some comments regarding the post but it's my first time.

Answer (score 0):

First you must change function name, you cannot user "throw" beacause it is a reserved word in javascript , see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

```
 var add = null;

 function throwFunc() {
    var artist = document.getElementById("artist").value;
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var label = document.getElementById("label").value;

    newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    newRow.onclick = function () {
            showRow(this)
    };
    newRow.innerHTML = "<td>" + artist + "</td>" + "<td>" + title + "</td>" + "<td>" + label + "</td>";
    add = document.getElementById("tabelkaa");
    add.appendChild(newRow);
 }

  function showRow(x) {
    alert("Row index is: " + x.rowIndex);
 }
window.onload = function () {
    var plus = document.getElementById("plus");
    plus.addEventListener("click", throwFunc);
 }
```

Note: Jquery is better for DOM manipulation

Comment: Oh right, thank you. Now I see.
But I have one more problem. Recently it works but now pops up: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
It's just that I want to change img above a number of rows.

  `oRows = addj.getElementsByTagName('tr');
iRowCount = oRows.length;
  if(iRowCount>4)`
 //here photo change code'